# How to export an existing Git private project (earlier hosted on GitHub) from localbox to GitLab?

Tags: git, github, export, local, gitlab

I have project in my localbox which was version controlled with Git and it was hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/). If that project was a private one and I was one of the collaborators then(not any more a collaborator now as a result the import feature in [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in) to clone an existing GitHub repo won't work in my case and I'm not even sure if it is supposed to work for private GitHub projects for which one has only a collaborator access).

If I'd like to push all my commits with regard to that project (through what I have with me on my localbox) to a private repo on GitLab so that I can easily traceback my work done(in terms of my commits, pull requests, comments etc.). With regard to that project is there a way I can do so using Git and GitLab? If yes, please let me know the steps involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove the remote origin that points to github and replace it with a new one

`git remote rm origin
git remote add origin yourGitLabRepoURL/project
git push origin master`

Source:
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

Comment: That worked, thank you.. Is this how I push my remaining branches as well related to the code repo?

Comment: You can do so by using `git push --all origin`